# Structs and immutable values in SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, swiftui

I have a strange problem with SwiftUI structs and I don't know if I'm doing it all wrong.

Basically I made a struct for a piece of my app called `Box`, and an environment object called data, which among other stuff it stores an array of `Box`.

Now, I know structs are value types and not reference types. If I were to switch to reference types like classes, then I wouldn't be able to use them in SwiftUI as a view. So I had to use a struct.

I am trying to modify a struct's  property inside the struct itself, in one of its methods. But for some reason, if I loop through the array (even by using indexes instead of a `forEach`), a copy of the struct is created with the initial value as if I had never modified it.

For example: (data is an instance of this following class)

```
//My environment object
class sharedStuff: ObservableObject {
    @Published var boxes: [Box]=[]
    func bankCall()-> Int {
        if !bankTurns.contains(data.turn) {
            var avg: Double=0
            var total: Double=1
            for index in 0..<data.boxes.count {
                print(data.boxes[index].state)
                if data.boxes[index].state>0 { print(data.boxes[index].state)}
                if data.boxes[index].state==0 {
                    avg+=Double(data.boxes[index].price)
                    total+=1
                    //print("average: \(avg) total: \(total)")
                } // state is 0
                if data.boxes[index].state==2 {
                // And so on...
```

The struct is here:

```
struct Box: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var data: sharedStuff
    let index: Int
    let number: Int
    let price: Int
    let cover: String
    let sound:SoundItem?
    @State var state: Int
```

This state always is 0 even if I change it form here.

I do a lot of weird things to try to change all of the states possible but nothing works.

This is func tap, located inside the struct. It is called whenever a button inside the view is pressed. The view is also inside the struct, but it is irrelevant to this question.

```
func tap() {
    self.state=2
    data.boxes[index].state=2
}
```

Data is just an environment object:

```
@EnvironmentObject var data: sharedStuff
```

This is included in the main view as well as the Box view.

But the issue occurs within the bankCall function, it is unable to see that I changed the state in the tap function.

The tap function is a member of the problematic structure, `Box`.

Bank call is a method inside `sharedStuff`, which data is an instance of. So since it is an environment object, and boxes is marked with @Published, it should be shared between views.

I truncated most of the code but you get the idea. No matter what I do, the loop in the function bankCall always returns 0, which is the initial value of the state var in the struct when it is initialized.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add swift/swiftui tag to the question.
Thank you.

Comment: So  sorry, I thought I had added it, my bad

Comment: I don't understand your question. Where is `func tap` located? Where is the array of `boxes` being assigned to? you showed bits and pieces of your code, but it's unclear how they connect together. Also, the whole value-type vs reference-type in SwiftUI - you might have a misunderstanding there

Comment: I have edited the question. The tap function is inside the struct. So it's modifying self, and I also modify the index directly, so both coppies. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You are still missing some of the context we need to help.  Your tap function updates data.boxes[index] and your bankCall alters data.boxes[index] (instead of it's own array boxes), but you never show where you defined data.  Is it a global?

Comment: Oh, yeah, data is a global instance of sharedStuff, sorry.

Comment: Still not enough context.  Can you add the relevant parts of your view to the question?  You make statements like "state is marked as @State", but don't give us that context.  The context of your view is likely the cause of your problems, so without showing that, we likely can't help.

Comment: @OriolGomez So you have a view, are you using `@ObservedObject` to update the view whenever `sharedStuff` changes? Please include the code of the view you are trying to update.

Comment: OK, i added more information. Sorry for my bad explanations.

Comment: View models shouldn't hold views, like `Box`. They hold and manipulate data, and then SwiftUI creates views based on that data, for example with `ForEach(dataElements) { data in someView(data) }`.